# Всплывающее соощение из excel по условию

Tags: windows, excel, powershell, поиск-программ

Задача: в excel столбец "Дата", когда остается до наступления какой либо даты, N дней, то windows напоминает об этом всплывающем сообщением, либо другим объектом message. Каким инструментом лучше реализовать? Батником возможно такую логику сконструировать ? Что посоветуете? Спасибо.

Comment: То есть файл тихо-мирно лежит себе где-то, а некая программа регулярно туда лазит и организует вывод сообщений? Или как? *Что посоветуете?* VBA-кодом при внесении изменений в файл Excel формировать соотв. задание в планировщике ОС.

Comment: @Akina С файлом постоянно работают, некая программа при включении ПК организует проверку столбца по условию и вывод на экран сообщение если условие не выполняется

Comment: @Akina я так понимаю проще vba ничего не придумаешь, неужели придется изучать

Comment: *некая программа при включении ПК* Ну так и пишите эту некую программу. На каком-нибудь вменяемом языке высокого уровня. И в автозагрузку её. Про батники забудьте - из них получить данные, лежащие в Excel, малореально. Но я бы думал в направлении поиска и использования уже написанных программ-напоминалок, коих реально аки грязи.

Comment: @Akina напониналка не будут лезть в excel, проверять по условию столбец

Comment: @AlekseyNikolaev, а как она тогда будет знать чё выводить, если не через эксель?

Comment: @donRumata я имею ввиду что решений готовых нет,  надо свое писать

Comment: Сообщение нужно не чаще раза в сутки. Если с *Excel* хоть редко, но работают, то почему не сделать вывод сообщений из VBA, не задействуя сторонние инструменты?

Comment: @vikttur для этого нужно долго курить маны по vba. Я предполагал, что возможно реализовать через .bat или powershell и автозагрузку его или планировщик.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Реализация на *VBA*.

При открытии книги выводится сообщение, если до даты осталось не более 3 дней (или просрочено) . Код разместить в модуле *ЭтаКнига* книги *Excel*.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' сообщение, если от сегодняшней даты до указанной <= 3 дня'
    If Worksheets("Лист1").Range("A2").Value - Date <= 3 Then
        MsgBox "Осталось не больше 3 дней!", 64, "ОТЧЕТ ГОРИТ!!!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Чтобы обработать столбец с датами, нужно добавить цикл для проверки каждого значения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ar()
Dim sStr As String
Dim dFinish As Date
Dim lRw As Long, i As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' последняя строка с датой'
        If lRw < 2 Then Exit Sub ' дат нет, выходим'
        ar = .Range("A1:C" & lRw).Value ' диапазон в переменную'
        dFinish = .Range("D2").Value ' количество дней'
    End With

    For i = 2 To lRw ' циклом по строкам'
        If ar(i, 1) - Date <= dFinish Then ' если подходит срок'
            If ar(i, 3) <> "выполнено" Then ' если нет отметки о выполнении'
                ' записываем текст в строковую переменную'
                sStr = sStr & Chr$(10) & Format(ar(i, 1), "dd/mm/yy") & "_" & ar(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' если текст есть, показываем сообщение'
    If sStr <> "" Then MsgBox "Осталось не больше 3 дней!" & _
                        Chr$(10) & sStr, 64, "СРОКИ"
End Sub
```

Comment: Разместись две функции Workbook_Open() в одном модуле ?

Comment: Исключение Ambiguous name detected

Comment: Нет. Это два варианта решения. Первый код упрощенный, для проверки одной даты. Во второй процедуре проверяется диапазон ячеек.

Comment: что то не верно, выдаетпредупреждение для всех дат в столбце, без разницы <3 или >3

Comment: заменил условие на If Date - ar(i, 1) <= 3 Then вроде работает

Comment: box которые появляется при открытии книги возможно как то стилизовать?

Comment: Нет, сообщения стандартные. Но можно создать форму пользователя и вызывать ее вместо  *MsgBox*

Comment: If sStr <> "" Then Userform "Осталось не больше 3 дней!" & _
                        Chr$(10) & sStr, 64, "СРОКИ" ? так ошибка

Comment: *Userform* - ее еще создать надо. Это выходит за рамки вопроса.

Comment: Создал, присвоил имя, поэтому имени вызываю

Comment: На форме должны быть элементы, в которые выводить сообщение. Это другой вопрос. Обсуждение перешло границы заглавного вопроса.

Comment: У меня столбец с датами не в A. Где надо поправить код, чтобы он искал даты не в столбце A. а допустим в D?

Comment: Разобрался спасибо еще раз